# How to correctly submit a form via ajax containing a resized image with the cropper library even without selecting an image

Tags: javascript, ajax, cropper

I have a problem with my code, I have a form that contains data and images that can be resized from the cropper library. My problem is that when I submit the form without selecting an image, my ajax call does not work properly.